# Discrete Fourier Transform of the Gaussian

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fourier-series, fourier-transform, image-processing

I encountered the following question in a Digital Image Processing examination:

> Find the 2D DFT of $\frac{1}{2 \pi \sigma^2} e^{-\frac{(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$ where $x_0, y_0$ are integers and $x_0, y_0 \in \left[ -\frac{N}{2}, \frac{N}{2} \right]$.
> We are considering an image where pixel intensities can be real but the pixels are discrete and in the range $[-N, N] \times [-N, N]$

## My approach

I used the formula which was given in the question paper:
$$ F(u, v) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{x = 0}^{N-1} \sum_{y = 0}^{N-1} f(x, y)e^{-\frac{2 \pi j}{N}(ux + vy)} $$
For simplicity, I tried to first solve for the case where $x_0, y_0 \geq 0$
$$
\begin{align}
\therefore F(u, v) &= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{x = 0}^{N-1} \sum_{y = 0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{2 \pi \sigma^2} e^{-\frac{(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{2 \pi j}{N}(ux + vy)} \\
\therefore F(u, v) &= \frac{1}{2 \pi \sigma^2 N} \sum_{x = 0}^{N-1} \sum_{y = 0}^{N-1} e^{-\frac{(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{2 \pi j}{N}(ux + vy)} \\
\therefore F(u, v) &= \frac{1}{2 \pi \sigma^2 N} \left( \sum_{x = 0}^{N-1} e^{-\frac{(x - x_0)^2}{2 \sigma^2} - \frac{2 \pi j u x}{N}} \right) \left( \sum_{y = 0}^{N-1} e^{-\frac{(y - y_0)^2}{2 \sigma^2} - \frac{2 \pi j v y}{N}} \right) \\
\therefore F(u, v) &= \frac{1}{2 \pi \sigma^2 N} g(u) g(v)
\end{align} 
$$
Hee, we define $g(\cdot)$ as
$$g(t) = \sum_{x = 0}^{N-1} e^{-\frac{(x - x_0)^2}{2 \sigma^2} - \frac{2 \pi j t x}{N}}$$
Now, I tried to evaluate $g$ using some of the standard methods used to evaluate summations in DFT. I tried:

- Trying to write the summation as a GP. However, due to the square term in the exponent, this is clearly not possible.
- Trying to telescope the series
- Trying to differentiate and see if the derivative is easier to evaluate

## The given solution

While the professor hasn't given a solution, he said that the DFT of the Gaussian is the Gaussian with the variance as the multiplicative inverse of the original Gaussian. While I know that this property is true for the Fourier Transform, I could not find any references online or in the reference texts provided that claim the same.

Can someone please help me understand what is the closed form solution and if it is indeed the Gaussian, how can I derive it? Thanks!